# New to C Programming - stuck on char string assignment

Tags: c

I'm trying to build a quick program in C (I'm new to this). It lets the user define some questions and possible answers first, then the program asks the questions. In the final version, if the answer is correct the next question is asked otherwise the program ends.

This is how far I went until there but I'm not sure everything is correct (I'm still a bit confused on which size needs to be assigned for each defined variable (I put 5 for "answer" but not sure why!). The program behaves weirdly when the 3rd question is asked (it is not displayed properly). Can anybody please advise?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Quest {
char  title[255];
char  option1[255];
char  option2[255];
char  answer[5];
};



int main( ) {
int i;
char name[255];
char user_answ[5];
struct Quest Question[2];     

for(i=0; i<3; i++)
 {
     printf("Enter q%d title:\n", i+1);
     fgets(Question[i].title,sizeof(Question[i].title),stdin);

     printf("Enter q%d option1:\n", i+1);
     fgets(Question[i].option1,sizeof(Question[i].option1),stdin);

     printf("Enter q%d option2:\n", i+1);
     fgets(Question[i].option2,sizeof(Question[i].option2),stdin);

     printf("Enter q%d answer:\n", i+1);
     fgets(Question[i].answer,sizeof(Question[i].answer),stdin);

 }

/* Ask Name */
 printf("What is your name?\n");
fgets(name,sizeof(name),stdin);

printf("Hi %s! \n",name);
for(i=0; i<3; i++){

printf( "%s\n", Question[i].title);
printf( "1: %s\n", Question[i].option1);
printf( "2: %s\n", Question[i].option2);
printf( "Please enter your answer\n");
fgets(user_answ,sizeof(user_answ),stdin);
printf( "Your answer is %s\n",user_answ);
printf( "The right answer is %s\n",Question[i].answer);

}

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
struct Quest Question[2];
```

Writing this you took an array of the structure having 2 members. They are identified as `Question[0]` and `Question[1]`. But when you run the loop from i=0 to i=2, then `Question[2]` will not be available.

So write this: `for(i=0; i<2; i++)`. The loop will run now for i=0 and i=1 only.

Comment: Thanks @najat That's a good start. Is it the same problem with my two variables anwer and user_answer, what is the best size for them? It is supposed to be "1" or "2" but it behaves weirdly when I use char answer[1]. Also how can I compare user_answer and answer when it comes to validate the entry? –

Comment: `if (strcmp (user_answ, Question[i].answer) == 0) { "... they match ...")`

Answer (score 2):

You want input for three questions, and you output three questions. But you only create an array for ***two*** questions.

When creating an array, the value in the square brackets (`[]`) is the number of elements in the array, not the top index.

What happens now is that you go out of bounds of the array you have, and you will experience *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Thanks @joachim-pileborg  That's a good start. Is it the same problem with my two variables anwer and user_answer, what is the best size for them? It is supposed to be "1" or "2" but it behaves weirdly when I use char answer[1]. Also how can I compare user_answer and answer when it comes to validate the entry?

Comment: @user2475110 Remember that strings in C needs to be *terminated*. Therefore a string of a single character needs an array of two elements: One for the character in the string, and one for the terminator. A string with five characters need an array of six elements, and so on.

Comment: So in theory **anwer** and **user_answer** should be of size 2 as I'm only expecting a single character as a possible answer. Problem is the program behaves weirdly if I chose a number lower than 4 (I think.

Comment: @user2475110 Yes, if you only want a single character, then the arrays need to have two elements. Could the problem be that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) adds the newline into the buffer (if it fits)? That should not be a problem with a two-element array though.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Quest Question[2];
```

You only have an array of two question, you can't fill and display 3.

Change that 2 to a 3.

You can see this like telling the compiler

> Make a variable name **Question** which will contains **2** variables of type **struct Quest**

Of course this is a little simplified, but you can understand that you need **3** variables.